# Suitable alloys of platinum or gold for weaponry

Tags: science-based, metals

In the magic system I'm developing, denser metals (like platinum or gold) can store up energy in order to fuel spells at the user's need. A weapon made of said metals would be very useful, since the wielder would be able to store vast amounts of power into it (and even place enchantments into the blade), and it would also be incredibly expensive and rare (which those metals already are).

However, those metals are also unsuitable for use as weaponry, which leads to the question: are there any alloys of them which would be suitable for, say, making swords and axes? Alloys aren't as efficient as the pure material for storage, but would still be a lot more efficient than something made of steel, or even lead.

Comment: What have you searched on your own?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica mostly searches in here (to see if anyone asked something similar) and on google, but the best thing I got so far was a pdf exemplifying platinum alloys for jewelry. But since I'm not very familiar with the technical terms used, I couldn't figure if any of those was what I'm looking for

Comment: What precise qualities are you looking for - is density the primary consideration, the higher the better as it were? (And presumably trying to keep the price down.)

Comment: AFAIK, [platinum-iridium alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platinum-iridium_alloy) is the only alloy of platinum made in bulk (where "bulk" is to be understood as suitable for a precious metal) specifically for its hardness. It has a hardness midway between mild steel and hardened steel; that is, much better than ancient Roman swords of soft iron, a little worse than medieval Damascus steel swords. (And let's hope that the magic system allows for modern-ish metallurgy; platinum cannot be processed with medieval technology, having a very high melting point.)

Comment: @Tantalus'touch. Higher densities would be better for energy storage, but would make the weapons too heavy to wield properly. A balance between density, hardness and durability would be best, as the weapon would need to keep an edge, be able to take a few hits, and still be useful as a "magic battery". I can't reasonably want something as good as steel, and I don't want to handwave it

Comment: @AlexP that looks very good

Comment: Why make a gold sword? I could beat a man with a gold sword with a normal sword and a gold bar in my pocket. I have a stronger, sharper sword and a larger, purer mass of gold. Mixing the two just creates a weaker version of both.

Comment: A side note: In your world you could also make fake gold swords or whatever you like by coating a sword with TiN. Its shingy golden color matches that of actual gold very closely. Nowadays we use physical or chemical vapor deposition techniques to deposit TiN, I guess you would have to search for a suitable method if you are interested. I can image the look on the adventurers face when the gold sword from the dragon's stache is really just a replica.

Comment: Have you considered tungsten? It's more dense than gold, far cheaper (right now something on the order of 5.8 thousand times cheaper), and has much better properties for a weapon (though not as good as steel on average). Also, blunt weapons and some projectiles absolutely want to be made of high density materials, so they may be viable options here (maybe that's why staves are so popular among mages?).

Comment: @Thorne you would be able to place several enchantments on a gold sword, and they would be a lot more cost-effective and last a lot longer than any enchantment placed on a steel sword. With the gold bar you could store more energy for your own use, but the sword you'd wield would be a lot less useful for someone who isn't a wizard but would like to use an enchanted weapon. The idea of adventurers finding enchanted gold bars would be kinda amusing though

Comment: Real life depleted Uranium is used for very heavy bullets today.  Good for armor piercing due to its mass, but I'm not sure if your tech level allows for firearms.

Comment: Why should your magic system be bound by ordinary metallurgy, chemistry or physics?

If you're really talking about denser metals what, technically, is wrong with lead?

Storing power in a weapon raises two questions:

     What happens to the weapon when that power is used?

     Why use a weapon? Why not a wand?

Why not invent a new alloy - or a new metallic element?

What says alloys aren't as efficient for storage? Why would they not be more efficient, as in real life they're often more suitable for whatever?

Comment: IRL electrum? You can aways use metal wiring as the magical channel and decorate your iron swords/axes accordingly.

Comment: If JRPGs have taught me anything, it's that the more valuable the metal, the better a weapon it makes.

Comment: Hoity-toity wizards comparing their gold-inlaid swords and staves, and then a hedge wizard comes along and gently lays his hand on his one-ton ox-cart load of scrap metal..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you want is β-Ti<sub>3</sub>Au which technically is an intermetallic of gold and titanium. Apparently Tony Stark was right about a titanium gold alloy being a good choice for his suits.

https://phys.org/news/2016-07-lab-titanium-gold-alloy-harder-steels.html

The density is similar to titanium. Harder than steel, half the specific gravity.

A sword forged from this stuff would certainly be magical. Lighter, stronger, harder, sharper, corrosion resistant and extremely difficult to forge. It's difficult to form the alloy in the first place, and then you get the α-phase (same hardness as straight titanium). The harder β-phase forms only at extremely high temperatures.

Oh and it's a red-gold colour. You can give it various conflicting backstories of being forged with the blood of dragons and suchlike.

---

I was thinking about how mediaeval smiths might produce such a thing and you're going to *love* the answer: in the side of a volcano. And he'll still need coal dust and a fan. How exactly the smith is supposed to survive in such an environment is your problem. I expect that such weapons will have been made by your gods, giving a whole new meaning to "limited edition".

A regular forge won't be hot enough. It will return the material to the α-phase, which is not a horrible material for a sword but won't hold an edge the way the β-phase will. Any reforging of the Sword that was Broken would be an epic quest in itself; you would need to enlist the aid of your world's equivalent to Hephaestus/Vulcan.

Note that being very hard and keeping a superb edge is not the same as unbreakable. With stupid handling such a sword would be easier to break than iron because where iron will bend, this will snap.

It would be within the strength of a big fighter to apply enough torsion to snap it. But this only improves the item from a game perspective because players take care about how they use it, or face the ire of other players for destroying a unique item that's nearly impossible to reforge.

These physical qualities also affect the *type* of sword. To mitigate the risk of shattering, the blade needs significant depth in the cutting plane — like a scimitar. Long and thin is just begging for failure (but you might start out this way and have Vulcan fix the design flaw if they've been good little players).

---

Interesting comments. I don't think having half the density of steel represents a problem. Have you ever lifted a real sword? They're heavy! A lighter sword is a speed and stamina advantage.

The tensile strength of mild steel is about 400MPa with a Young's Modulus of 210GPa. By contrast most titanium alloys have a tensile strength from 1000 to 1390MPa and a Young's Modulus of 103GPa .

Straight titanium is similar in hardness to 304 stainless steel, and although I could not find a hardness value for beta βTi<sub>3</sub>Au it is widely described as "four times harder than titanium" hence my razor blade comments.

Bronze swords were thicker to offset the lower material strength. With half the density you can double the thickness and come out the same weight. While aluminium bronzes can have up to 780MPa tensile strength, the alloys available to the Greeks were about 230MPa.

Comment: This is just plain awesome!  It would make an amazing magical weapon!

Comment: The best part is it's not made up.

Comment: While I'm not sure it answers the question, I do have to say it's too good not to bring up!

Comment: Not only this fits all the criteria, but the material also looks awesome. Found my magic sword

Comment: Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic - Arthur C Clarke

Comment: Not enough upvotes for this level of awesome.  Well played sir. :)

Comment: I just read over the provided paper and it seems, that the team really only tested the hardness of the material - even after looking for other sources I couldn't find information on things like Young's Modulus, Yield-Point, etc. I have no idea, how good of a sword Ti3Au would make because hardness alone doesn't make blade (e.g. glass). Also you are inable to selectively temper the material (maybe with alpha-Ti3Au? Temperature differences would be extrem). Additionally, with a density of around half that of steel your weapon would have next to no inertia and worse mana-storage than plain steel.

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous - for other Ti beta phase alloys, YM is consistently 103GPa with tensile strength from 1000 to 1390MPa. 

The density issue re the magic system I have ignored. Don't spoil their fun, next you'll have Ironman in a sentence about reaction mass.

Current applications employ selective tempering.

Comment: @PeterWone Didn't want to spoil anyones fun :P - correct me if I'm wrong (I am not to well versed in mat-science/enginnering) but the numbers you posted essentially mean, that you have an incredibly flexible material, that you cannot really break by snapping (requiring about twice the bending steel would need to snap)? That might make a good Rapier?

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous brittle is relative. Martensite is brittle compared to austenite. That's why you can snap razor blades. As you astutely noted, selective tempering is the answer. Given the lattice I would expect high rigidity. One would use this sword very differently. It is not a bludgeon or stabbing weapon, it is a huge razor blade. Mail would be a good defence but neck and joint slash attacks would be devastating.

Comment: Don't wanna be rude, but this is asking for a correction:
"Have you ever lifted a real sword? They're heavy!"
Have you? Nope, they're not!

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news but a volcano forge would actually be worse than than regular coal forge, magma is quite cold by comparison.

Comment: @john next you'll be telling me a secret island base staffed by top heavy women in gold lamé bikinis isn't a good idea.

More seriously, this stuff is very hard. You don't need to quench it and you do need to anneal it slowly.

Comment: @BIOStheZerg your generalisation is as flawed as mine. An epee is light, a hand-and-a-half is not. If you think it is, you haven't been swinging it for long.

Answer (score 31):

***Crushing weapons:***

I was going to go with the inlay answer, but as another alternative, why aren't your magical weapons metal staves, rods, and Maces? Here, other than a strong handle, the weight of the weapon is what makes it effective. I don't know what properties your magic imbues, so I can't speak for what magical properties the weapon would have. Mass in a crushing weapon is valuable to cripple and maim armored OR unarmored opponents; By the time knights started wearing plate armor, sharp swords were undesirable and good only for fighting lesser opponents.

Similarly, heavy axes relied on small cutting blades and a lot of force and leverage. Plate everything but add mass with gold (not sure why lead isn't on top, as it's cheap, but hey, your rules).

If these weapons are merely batteries for magical storage, A simple Gold rod (perhaps with a steel shaft in the middle) would be an almost hallmark weapon of wizards. Just flashing a golden mace would say "Don't mess with me, I'm a wizard." On the other hand, stealing a wizard's rod would leave him vulnerable. I'd suggest a sort of breastplate with gold strapped directly to the wizard's body.

Comment: Now I'm feeling like a real dingus for not thinking of maces and staves sooner. +1

Comment: Lead is less than 60% the density of Gold, so you for the same weight you can have a smaller weapon, *and* a higher density (which may mean more magic stored).  Lead is better than Silver though - both denser *and* cheaper.

Comment: "...golden breastplate" -3 defensive roll for lightning attacks :)

Comment: Nope. Gold is too soft (you can literally chew it). Make it a blunt weapon and you will deform it a lot with every swing. It also won't hold shape as a staff for a wizard.

Comment: @ Renan I considered that, which was why I suggested a steel core. My specific thought was actually a flanged mace with a big mass of gold at the center for most of the mass. Honestly, I suspect if you're a wizard, you're mostly using this as a magic sink, and an old-fashioned weapon works best for actual fighting. But in a battle, it's the weapon you have, not the weapon you want.

Comment: @Renan more likely to make a hollow core to fill with gold. it will hold the shape of a staff, it will just weigh several hundred pounds,  the wizard would be ripped. .

Comment: @John now that would be awesome!

Answer (score 12):

## Use Gold Inlays instead of Alloys

Unless there's a strict requirement for the entire blade to be made of gold/platinum, don't use alloys.  There will be plenty of compromises in quality, hardness, cost and utility that you may not want to make.

### Cost

Getting a high quality and hard alloy from gold or platinum maybe possible but expensive.  A claymore (2.5kg) made of pure gold (to establish an upper bound) would be USD\$144K.  Compare that a ton of steel is USD\$980.

### Workmanship

It's easy to find a blacksmith to work iron.  It's easy to find a jeweler to work gold and platinum.  It's *very* rare to find someon who can do both.  Unless there's a very long history of this kind of workmanship, the number of practitioners in magical sword making is going to be very small.

### Material Compromises

Gold is very soft with a hardness of 2.5.  Platinum is 3.5.  Iron is 4.0 ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardnesses_of_the_elements_(data_page)))  Any alloy of gold or platinum is going to have to fight that lack of hardness.  The metallurgy could get quite complicated to get satisfactory alloys.

### Recommendations

Do a gold or platinum inlay instead of alloy. This allows your blacksmiths to forge a good sword and your jewelers to do beautiful work. The complexities of metallurgy to go away too.

Comment: I like that idea very much, but the fact that a gold weapon is enormously expensive and hard to make is actually interesting to me, as I was envisioning those weapons as a super rare, "found one on a dragon's hoard" kind of thing.

Comment: Just a note, the hardness of elemental iron is fairly low, but the actual iron used to make swords contains many different compounds, especially martensite, which is a product of heat treatment, that are quite a bit harder, increasing the difference between gold/platinum and "iron" swords.

Answer (score 10):

**Don't make an alloy**

Use the gold in other ways. Use gold for the pommel to counterbalance the blade. Use gold inlay on the blade. Put some gold in the grip.

[image]

This way you don't weaken the steel of the blade and don't ruin the purity of the gold battery.

Comment: "Pommel" was literally the first thing that came to mind. Hardness doesn't matter there, and weight is even advantageous.

Comment: gold inlay was actually \, well not common, but common for nobility.

Answer (score 8):

**Magic power steering**

People love gold swords.  Sometimes they have them in weddings even.  But in real life gold is heavy and soft so it would not make a very functional tool.   Even those wedding swords are not solid because they would be so heavy they would pull the groom's pants down.

I am reminded of the stealth aircraft which require a ["fly-by-wire"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly-by-wire) interface because they are inherently unstable and unaerodynamic.  Without the tech they cannot fly.   So too your gold sword.  As made it is pretty much unusable except for pulling down grooms' pants.  But lay on that magic and it becomes light and sharp and also whatever else you want - maybe it can be thrown accurately and return to your hand, or sing songs around the campfire.

People who are digging magic swords might not need to see accurate metallurgy.  Make your sword solid gold and maximally awesome.  If the magic has the potential of wearing off, make your your grooms have maximally awesome undershorts.

Answer (score 4):

Metals having density around 20:

Gold (density 19.3) is soft and not really good material for weaponry. But it can make a good decoration.

Light platinides Rutenium, Rhodium, Paladium and especially heavy platinides (Osmium, Iridium, Platinum) are extremely hard. Osmium is densest - something like 22.5

Tungsten - density 19.3 (like gold), but a lot harder. Crazy metallurgy, hardest to melt (not that others are a lot easier...)

Uranium - density 19.1 . It contains a lot of magic by itself.

In our everyday world, 90% Platinum + 10% Iridium alloy is used for creating measurement standards exactly because it is hard. I am almost sure that it is harder than steel.

Any item made from these metals is surprisingly heavy. For comparison - iron is 7.6, lead is 11.2, copper is 8.9.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't a gold or platinum weapon be magically hardened?  Not only would the cost of making such a weapon be great, but you could have varying levels of hardness based on how complex the magic is.  This would introduce varying levels of cost and could also introduce the need to "refuel" the weapon, which would prevent infinite weapons and create true loss.  True loss is what keeps an economy going!